# Extended Linked List methods not working in separate classes main method

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

This is the class that extends LinkedList I am using the addtopq to make a priority que system where the 1st element of the que is the String and the 2nd is the priority related to that string. Ignore the Exception

```
class PQ extends LinkedList {

public void addtopq(String s, Integer p){
    if (p<1 || p>20) throw new InvalidPrioty("Priority number must be between 1 and 20");
    int pos = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    LinkedList nlist = new LinkedList();

    if (this==null){
        addLast(s);
        addLast(p);
        System.out.println(this);
    }
} 
else {
       while (i<size()){
            int x  = Integer.valueOf(get(i).toString());
            if (p > x) pos = 1;
            else  if (p==x){
                pos = 0;
                break;
            }
            else if (p < x) {
                pos = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (pos==1){
            addLast(s);
            addLast(p);
        }
        if (pos==-1||pos==0){
            for (k=0; k<(i-1); k++) nlist.add(j, get(j));
            nlist.addLast(s);
            nlist.addLast(p);
            for (k=k+1 ; k<size(); k++) nlist.add(get(k));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the main file which refuses to add the the 2 new Objects into the list:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PQ list = new PQ();
    list.addtopq("first", 1);
    System.out.println(list);



}
```

I am getting [] in the output instead of [first, 1] that I would like. Do I need to create a constructor in the PQ class?

Comment: Why are you initializing the nList in addToPq..

Comment: OMG `if (this == null)` ???

Comment: Is this an exercise? Otherwise you could use a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You assign value to `nlist` but never use it.  Also, `this==null` is always true.

Comment: First of all why are you extending LinkedList to make a Priority Queue.. that doesnt make ANY sense to me at all.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov `this` will never be `null` =\

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov It is used later I just didn't want to show all the code yet.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes it is how would I use a priorityQueue?

Comment: I've posted a link in the `PriorityQueue` name. Enter and you'll find the documentation for the class. You can even do this: `Queue<MyData> queue = new PriorityQueue<MyData>();`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yea .. but there were so many questions that .. forget it.. Deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PQ list = new PQ();

        //Insert test code here:
        list.addtopq("First",20);
        list.addtopq("Second",3);
        list.addtopq("Third", 1);
        list.addtopq("Forth",3);
        list.addtopq("Fifth",2);
        list.addtopq("Sixth",4);
        list.tostring();

import java.util.LinkedList;

class InvalidPrioty extends RuntimeException{
    public InvalidPrioty(String s){
        super(s);
    }
}

class PQ extends LinkedList{

    public void addtopq(String s, Integer p){
        if (p<1 || p>20) throw new InvalidPrioty("Priority number must be between 1 and 20");
        System.out.println("Adding "+'"'+s+'"'+" with priority "+p);
        int pos = 0;
        int k;
        int i = 1;
        PQ nlist = new PQ();
        //The list will initially be empty so the first call the the addtopqmethod
        // will add the objects to the queue and avoid errors when checking if objects values
        // are greater than null.
        if (isempty()){
            addLast(s);
            addLast(p);
        }else {
           while (i<size()){
               // Creates an object to see whether the priority in the item being added is higher
               // than the one in the queue already.
                Integer x  = Integer.valueOf(get(i).toString());
               //The loop will break if priority is less than or equal to x so that it can place it behind the items
               //with higher or the same priority. I assumed that as long as all the strings in the list with the same
               //priority were together, that it wouldn't matter what order they in.
                if (p > x) pos = 1;
                else  if (p<=x){
                    pos = 0;
                    break;
                }
               i=i+2;
            }
            //Adds to the end of the que as it has the largest priority
            if (pos==1){
                addLast(s);
                addLast(p);
            }
            if (pos==0){

                //Adds everything up to the one being replaced into a seperate list...
                for (k=0; k<(i-1); k++) nlist.add(k, get(k));
                //Adds the new String with its priority into the List...
                nlist.addLast(s);
                nlist.addLast(p);
                //Adds the rest of the items
                for (; k<size(); k++) nlist.add(get(k));
                //Clears the list and adds the new order
                clear();
                addAll(nlist);
                nlist.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isempty(){
        if (contains(null)) return true;
        else return false;
    }


Output:

Adding "First" with priority 20
Adding "Second" with priority 3
Adding "Third" with priority 1
Adding "Forth" with priority 3
Adding "Fifth" with priority 2
Adding "Sixth" with priority 4

Queue Contents: <"Third":1,"Fifth":2,"Forth":3,"Second":3,"Sixth":4,"First":20>
```

Thanks for the help though guys really appreciated it :)

Answer (score 0):

More correct implementation of adding items to list would look like this:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class PQ extends LinkedList {

    public void addtopq(String s, Integer p) {
        addLast(s);
        addLast(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PQ list = new PQ();
        list.addtopq("first", 1);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Looking into how many basic mistakes you've made into code I'd suggest to go through link recommended by [Luiggi Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065197/luiggi-mendoza) and recommendations given in comments. Going through basic course on data structures wouldn't hurt as well.

Comment: java.util.LinkedList is imported at the top but adding the main method into the PQ class didn't change a thing. I've shown the rest of the addtopq method which might make it a little bit more clear why I wanted to use the if(this==null).

Comment: `this` is never null. Try to print result of `this == null` as test.

Comment: So what do I put there instead to check if the object list, in Main class, is equal to null?

Comment: Oh, even if object `list` in main class would be null (which is not) then you never would reach `if (this==null)` code. At point when you're calling 'list.addtopq("first", 1)` it will throw NullPointerException. Again, don't trust me - try for yourself to assign list to null in main method: `PQ list = null;`